# Electrical contacts overview ( switchgears )

Tags: voltage, switches

I'm currently working on an overview of contacts used in switchgears adjusted to medium voltages. What's more, I need descriptions of the contacts' shapes. I've tried to find some features of technical solutions I found but with a poor result.

It seems that nowadays everyone uses 2 contact's types :

1. RMF - Radial Magnetic Field
2. Contacts with dissipation difusion of the arc

It doesn't matter if it's vacuum breaker or insulated with SF6 one. I managed to find something more but it's still not enough.

Do you have any ideas where I could find more of the contacts ( shapes ) which are out of use ? ( historical, old devices ) The greatest difficulty is with finding so called inseparable not movable contacts and inseparable movable ones.

I would be very grateful for any tips/advices to this topic.

P.S. I've spoken with some manufacturers and the biggest companies in this trade but they all sounds quite similar.

Comment: If they're inseparable, how on earth would they ever be able to break a circuit?

Comment: If you thought I were looking only for breakers, then you are right. But I am looking for all types of contacts in switchgears ( medium voltages ). I know that I mentioned mainly about breakers and their contacts but I meant even motionless metal shapes.

Answer (score 1):

To find the proper English terminology, try searching for "medium voltage switchgear glossary." You might also search for "medium voltage switchgear technical guide," "... design guide," or "... application guide." Instead of the word "guide" you could also try "handbook" or "manual." Switchgear is not "adjusted to" medium voltage, it is designed for medium voltage.

The best information about design details will probably be found in papers published by IEEE. It is expensive get access to IEEE papers unless you can get access through a university library. If you find an abstract for a paper that looks promising, you could try to find the author's company or university and get a copy from their web site.

You may also be able to find information about patented features using google.com/patents. If you look at a patent, be sure to look at the references listed in it. Some of the references may be accessible and useful.

You could try google.com/images. You will get a lot of unrelated images, but you may be able to scan through the thumbnails and spot something useful.

Finding the kind of information that you seem to be looking for requires trying a lot of different search alternatives.

Comment: Thank you, sir. I've checked dozens of patents and still searching for proper things. Your "keywords" and tips will help without a doubt :)